# VBA - Compare two columns in one worksheet to two columns in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Compare two columns in one worksheet to two columns in another worksheet and get the corresponding values from some other columns with the columns match.

I have a unique id and line id in my first sheet. I have the same unique id and line id in my second sheet in a random order. I want to match the unique id and line id in my first sheet to the second sheet. I have some dates in the second sheet to be copied to the first one if both the unique id and line id matches. Wherever there is a match, the corresponding dates should be copied from the second sheet and pasted onto the first sheet near the matched unique id and line id.

I cannot upload the files since it is confidential.

I am not good at VBA, any help to solve this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**VBA Approach**

Below is a very simple approach to getting the values.  I'm pretty sure there are a lot of other more efficient approaches, but I'd only bother with those if this proved to be too slow.

To use - configure the first few settings as per the comments and hopefully away you go!

```
Sub RetrieveValues()

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")      'Sheet we are going to copy results into
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")      'Sheet we are going to copy results from

    'Identify the columns to use in the sheet we are copying into
    ws1UniqueIDCol = "B"         'Is the column with the first part of our lookup key - the unique id
    ws1LineIdCol = "C"           'Is the column with the second part of our lookup key - the line id
    ws1ValToWriteCol = "D"       'Is the column we want to put the found value into
    
    ws1StartRow = 3              'The row we want to start processing first, we can calc the last row automatically
    ws1EndRow = ws1.UsedRange.Rows(ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    
    
    'Identify the columns to use in the sheet we are copying from
    ws2UniqueIDCol = "B"         'Is the column with the first part of our lookup key - the unique id
    ws2LineIdCol = "C"           'Is the column with the second part of our lookup key - the line id
    ws2ValToCopyCol = "D"        'Is the column we want to copy the value from
    
    ws2StartRow = 3              'The row we want to start search first, we can calc the last row automatically
    ws2EndRow = ws2.UsedRange.Rows(ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    
    'iterate through search terms
    For i = ws1StartRow To ws1EndRow        '
        searchKey = ws1.Range(ws1UniqueIDCol & i) & ws1.Range(ws1LineIdCol & i)
        
         'if we have a non blank search term then iterate through possible matches
        If (searchKey <> "") Then
            For j = ws2StartRow To ws2EndRow
                 foundKey = ws2.Range(ws2UniqueIDCol & j) & ws2.Range(ws2LineIdCol & j)
                  
                  'if we have a match then copy the result and end this search (so we will take the first match found only)
                 If (searchKey = foundKey) Then
                    ws1.Range(ws1ValToWriteCol & i).Value2 = ws2.Range(ws2ValToCopyCol & j).Value2
                    Exit For
                 End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Non-VBA approach**

I tend to avoid VBA if I can - so if this doesn't need to be automated and you can add columns to the sheets, then the simplest solution would be not to use VBA at all.

Insert a new column in both the spreadsheets which is a key of the unique id and the line id concatenated together, then just use a vlookup to pull back the values.

- If you don't want it to stay dynamically linked then copy and paste values to get rid of the formulas.
- If there are occasions where the ID and line won't match, simply wrap the vloopup in an IFERROR function to have a default value (e.g. a blank) when it doesn't match

Sheet 1

```
ID  line  +Key+  Pseudo formula
X    13   X13   vlookup X13 in Key column of sheet 2  
Y    27   Y27   vlookup Y27 in Key column of sheet 2
```

Sheet 2

```
ID  line  +Key+  Value
X    13   X13   "The value to get"
Y    27   Y27   "Another value to get"
```

+Key+ = the new field to be inserted and is simply = ID & line

Comment: Thank you for your response but I have to do it on VBA. We want to automate this process.

Comment: Fair enough - I'll add a VBA answer too